# UITableView calling delegate method when datasource is empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method defined as so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PLOTCheckinTableViewCell *cell = (PLOTCheckinTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CheckinCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([self.items count] == 0){
        return cell;
    }
    NSDictionary *checkin = self.items[indexPath.row];
    // configure and return custom cell
}
```

I'm using a custom cell class (`PLOTCheckinTableViewCell`).

I faced an issue where the user would pull to refresh and then attempt to pull again before the first request had completed (on completion of the request, I reload the table data). When they did this, the app would crash and say that `indexPath.row` was basically out of bounds, ie. the array was empty.

By putting in this `IF` check above, I mitigated the crash.

However,

1. Why exactly does my `IF` check "work", I see no visual implications of returning the cell before it's been configured. This is confusing
2. Are there any better ways to guard against this happening (ie. the table data being reloaded with an empty array)? Surely the `numberOfRowsInSection` would have returned `array count` which would be 0? (if it was an empty array)

EDIT (further code)

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    float count = [self.items count];
    return count;
}

- (void)resetData {
    self.items = [NSMutableArray array];
}

-(void) refreshInvoked:(id)sender forState:(UIControlState)state {
    [self resetData];
    [self downloadHomeTimeline];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}

- (void)downloadHomeTimeline {
    [self.apiClient homeTimeline:self.page completionBlock:^(NSDictionary *data){
        for (NSDictionary *obj in data[@"items"]) {
            [self.items addObject:obj];
        }
        [self.itemsTableView reloadData];
    }];
}
```

Comment: May be it would help to see the implementation for the pull to refresh and numberOfRowForSection, if there is something like the second pull changes the content of the items array after numberOfRowForSection has returned a non zero number. I have noticed recently there is a noticeable delay after numberOfRowForSection has returned and cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.

Comment: @Antenehs yep, that sounds right. Edited question for clarity

Comment: You should return the count of `items` in `numberOfRowsInSection:` and `reloadData` on your table view once `items` is full of valid data.

Comment: After you do resetData you should immediately do a reloadData, so that the table view knows there are no elements in the array.  Otherwise, until the refresh completes, it will think that there are the old number of elements and will choke as you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couple of things that i would suggest to do.  Make sure that the `[self.itemsTableView reloadData]` is executed on the main thread and also i would put the `[self.refresControl endRefreshing]` in the completion block. This way it will stop the refresh when its done and you should not let the user more then once simultaneously.

```
 - (void)downloadHomeTimeline {
        [self.apiClient homeTimeline:self.page completionBlock:^(NSDictionary *data){
            for (NSDictionary *obj in data[@"items"]) {
                [self.items addObject:obj];
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.itemsTableView reloadData];
                [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
             }); 

        }];
    }
```

Also in the `numberOfRowsInSection` just return count

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.items count];
}
```

To add to the answer.  You should not reset the array before you receive new data.  While getting new data the user can still scroll the table and that means new cells will be created but your NSMutableArray doesn't have any data.  That is when you get the error and app crashes.  You would have to `[tableView reloadData]` to clear the table so that the tableView would know that there are 0 rows, which i don't think is your intent.

Let me know if that's solves the issue.

Comment: thank you and God bless you. That was a good tip to reload the table from main thread. I had suffered a lot by table view loading way to slowly( >10 secs) when reloaded from the completion block. The cellForRow was just never called for a long time after numberOfRowsForSection has returned. Then I simply decided that was a bug, and submitted my slow mo app as is. Time for an update now. Did I say thanks?

Comment: That's great!!! :)  Anything UI related has to be done in the main thread.  Otherwise it might not work correctly.  Happy Coding!